how to preload models that are not directly related
i have models like this
type TreatmentFormOutput struct {
    ID              uint
    OutputID        uint
    Output          Output
    TreatmentFormID uint
    Indicators      []OutputIndicator      // preload this
}

type Output struct {
    ID uint
}

type OutputIndicator struct {
    ID       uint
    OutputID uint
}

type TreatmentFormOutputIndicator struct {
    ID                uint
    TreatmentFormOutputID uint
    OutputIndicatorID uint
    LevelTarget       int
    LevelStart        int
    LevelEnd          int
}

how to preload OutputIndicators in TreatmentFormOutput based on TreatmentFormOutputIndicator?

I believe what you're looking for is how to eager load your model relationships in gorm.
When fetching your TreatmentFormOutput from the database, it should look like this: db.Preload("Indicators").Find(&treatments). See here for more on Eager Loading in form.
